# Error: "Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: this.filter is undefined"" in a list rendering in vue?

Tags: javascript, list, vue.js, vue-component, v-for

I am trying to build a component that creates filter buttons and then sends the type attribute in the filters object through the event bus to be handled elsewhere in my app. However, when I added the array of objects (filters) in the data section, I am getting an error of this.filter is not defined when I click on a button.

I would like to keep the filters array in this component because I am also trying to dynamically change the active class to whichever button has been clicked.

Am I missing something that has to do with props? Why am I unable to display the buttons when the data and v-for was on another component? These were the questions I have been asking myself in order of solving this issue.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button
      v-for="(filter, index) in filters"
      :key="index"
      :class="{ active: index === activeItem }"
      @click="emitFilter(), selectItem(index)"
      :filter="filter"
    >
      {{ filter.name }}
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import EventBus from '@/components/EventBus'
export default {
  props: {
    filter: { type: String }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      activeItem: 0,
      filterResult: '',
      filters: [
        { name: 'All', type: 'all' },
        { name: 'Holidays', type: 'holiday' },
        { name: 'Seasons', type: 'season' },
        { name: 'Events', type: 'custom' }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    emitFilter() {
      this.filterResult = this.filter
      EventBus.$emit('filter-catagories', this.filterResult)
    },
    selectItem(index) {
      this.activeItem = index
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

My button component is used in a filters component

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <span>filters</span>
      <FilterBtn />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import FilterBtn from '@/components/FilterBtn'


export default {
  components: {
    FilterBtn
      }
  // data() {
  //   return {
  //     filters: [
  //       { name: 'All', type: 'all' },
  //       { name: 'Holidays', type: 'holiday' },
  //       { name: 'Seasons', type: 'season' },
  //       { name: 'Events', type: 'custom' }
  //     ]
  //   }
  // }
}
</script>
```

As you can see, the commented section is where I had my filters originally, but I had to move them to the button component in order to add the active class.

Comment: You may have mixed up the order of parameters in v-for, it's usually (index, value). Also you should avoid overwriting the prop name.

Comment: @andypotato the order is correct how it is

Comment: I just confused on why the this.filter is undefined. What do you mean by overwriting the prop name @andypotato

Comment: @TylerMorales could you show us where you use your component? i guess you dont pass an prop to your button component? with `this.$props` you can check if its available

Comment: @Ifaruki I just edited the post to reflect those changes

Comment: See my answer below. I believe you need to remove the "prop" from your component (unless it's there for some other reason)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you were actually trying to access the `filter` iterator of `v-for="(filter, index) in filters"` from within `emitFilter()`. For this to work, you'd need to pass the `filter` itself in your `@click` binding:

```html
<button v-for="(filter, index) in filters"
        @click="emitFilter(filter)">
```

Then, your handler could use the argument directly:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    emitFilter(filter) {
      this.filterResult = filter
      //...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. And coincidentally, I just figured this out seconds before you posted. While not exactly the same, what I did was pass filter.type as an argument of emittFilter on @click and then used that in the method.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a prop called `filter` typed `string` to your component. When you output `{{ filter.name }}` you are actually referring to this property instead of the variable `filter` you create within the v-for loop.

Unless you passed a property called "filter" to your component, this property will be undefined. Therefore outputting `filter.name` will result in this error message.

Comment: I guess I'm just confused on how this component is taking in props. I thought props were passed from parent to children

Answer (score 0):

Yea you dont pass an prop to your component thats why its undefined.

```
<FilterBtn filter="test" />
```

Here i pass an prop named `filter` with the value of `test`.

Sure you could pass dynamic props. Just bind it.

```
<FilterBtn :filter="yourData" />
```

I need to ask: Are you passing an object or an string?

Because you defined your prop to be a string, but you actually use it as an object

```
  {{ filter.name }}
```

Maybe you should also set the type to Object.

```
  props: {
    filter: { type: Object }
  },
```

Comment: An object. My main goal is to take the type from the filters array and use it on the this.filterResult in the emitFilter() method. Quite simply, what I'm really trying to do is just pass the type of filter ('all', 'holiday'...)  to which ever button is clicked. I want to emit the type.